# Find the maximum and minimum value of variance.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be an arbitrary random variable  takes values in $\{0,1,2,...,10\}$. Then the minimum and  maximum values of variance of random variable $X$ are

1. $0$ and $30$
2. $1$ and $30$
3. $0$ and $25$
4. $1$ and $25$

But I don't know which one is true and how to approach? Help me out please.

Comment: $0$ is also non-negative, so you cannot exclude $1$ and $3$.

Comment: sorry my bad, edited

Comment: @5xum can you give me some hints?

Comment: I gave you an answer full of hints... :P

Answer (score 2):

For the minimal value of variance, think about the very word ***variance***. Variance measures how much a random variable **varies** in its values. So, intuitively, a random variable with low variance does not **vary** a lot, i.e. it sticks to the same value most of the time. What kind of function (not random variable, simply function) would you say varies the least?

For the maximum, to make a variable with large variance, you need a variable that swings very much between two very different values, so you want a lot of values to be either $0$ or $10$...

Comment: Ok is it same as calculating the variance of $-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5$? Then using $Var(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$

Comment: @HarryPotter Yes, because any variable on $-5-5$ can simply be shifted to $0-10$, by adding $5$ to it. This operation does not change the variance.

Comment: So $Var(X)$ is minimum when both $E(X^2)$ and $(E(x))^2$ is maximum, so minimum value is zero and similarly maximum value of variance is $25$

Comment: @HarryPotter The sentence "$Var(X)$ is minimum when both $E(X^2)$ and $E(X)^2$ is maximum" is false. $E(X)$ is maximum when $P(X=10)=1$, however that is **not** when the variance is maximum. You are, however, correct when you say that the maximum value of variance is $25$.

Comment: Hmmm so what I did $E(X)$ for $X=5$ is $5$, that is not correct right? I thought about treating $X=5$ as constant r.v and as $E(c)=c$ for $c$ constant.